# dataframe assign a array value to a cell

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to assign the value ('Data') of the first row of sub-group ('label') to its members. But the value is array(list) type:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.array([1, 2, 3, 10]), np.array([11,12,13,20]), np.array([11,13,14,20])], 'label' : ['a', 'a', 'b']})
df['first_member'] = df.groupby('label')['Data'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
print (df)
```

I will receive an error: `ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (2)`. I think it is the issue from assigning a array value.

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, the transform function expects to return the same result as the group size. It is possible to make a lamda function return the same result as the group size. Like this:

```py
df["first_member"] = df.groupby("label")["Data"].transform(
    lambda x: [x.iloc[0]] * len(x)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs because when assigning an array value to a column in pandas, it expects the length of the array to match the length of the index. In your case, the length of the "Data" column is 4, while the length of the index after grouping is 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.array([1, 2, 3, 10]), np.array([11, 12, 13, 20]), np.array([11, 13, 14, 20])], 'label': ['a', 'a', 'b']})

df['first_member'] = df.groupby('label')['Data'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0][0])

print(df)
```

Comment: sorry, you may misunderstand my meaning. 'first_member' is also array value. It should be np.array([1, 2, 3, 10]), np.array([11, 13, 14, 20]) i.e. the first value of 'Data' column in 'a' group and 'b' group